# Devise, how to reset password without current password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying when a user signs in for the first time is redirected to update(change) his password, but it seems I am missing something because the password is not changing.

Here is my code, am I missing?

## ApplicationHelper.rb

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
      edit_passwords_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
```

## PasswordsController.rb

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if current_user.update_without_password(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Password updated successfully."
      redirect_to signed_in_root_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem, please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

## views/passwords/_form.html.eb

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: passwords_path do |f| %>

  current_password:<br />
  <%#= f.password_field :current_password %><br />
  password:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
  password_confirmation:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tasks
  devise_for :users
  root 'tasks#index'
  resource :passwords
end
```

## Log

```
Started PATCH "/passwords" for ::1 at 2017-03-29 15:01:07 -0400
Processing by PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FIxTxsfOML7P7L+xWxznRDcedXOralm7PjSJtpUi+C/4erA6VsvLJACUPFNE+yYXjJFLKWLRYkn0n5VZV2R+6A==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update User"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-03-29 15:01:07 -0400
Processing by TasksController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"
  Rendered tasks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 25.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: did you try `put` instead of `patch`?

Comment: @aks how do I specify put?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for should help

Comment: @aks tried with 'put' but same result, password is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in various ways.

#### views/passwords/_form.html.eb

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: passwords_path do |f| %>
  password:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />

  password_confirmation:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />

  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### PasswordsController.rb

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Password updated successfully."
      redirect_to signed_in_root_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = current_user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```